Deleting edges from a bipartite graph
I have a bipartite graph $(n, n)$ and it's known it's not 2-regular, $n \ge 3$ and the degree of any vertex is $\ge 2$ and $\le n-1$. Is it always possible to delete edges from this graph to get 2-regular bipartite graph?

Hint: What's the Hall Marriage Theorem condition?

The answer is negative. The following is a bipartite graph satisfying the conditions proposed ($n = 5\ge 3$ and every degree is either $2$ or $3$) but with no generating $2$-regular subgraph, as the deletion of any edge would make some vertex have degree less then $2$.


A more straight forward approach is that a 2-regular bipartite graph implies $m= n$, so we can start out with the complete graph on $m > n$, and will never be able to get to a 2-regular bipartite graph. Given that, the $m=n$ case is the interesting case.
